# Cloudera installation failure

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install Cloudera on Centos7, when I install it using the command `sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin`, it shows the message that
[image: Install error]

> Cloudera Manager 5 is already installed. please uninstall it (by running /usr/share/cmf/uninstall.sh) before attempting to install it again.

When I try uninstalling it by running `sudo /usr/share/cmf/uninstall.sh` , it shows[image]

```
No such file or directory
```

I tried uninstalling everything using the script, `sudo yum remove 'cloudera-manager-*'`

and then removed the guid file:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/cloudera-scm-agent/cm_guid
```

And tried reinstalling it, but it still shows the same Fatal error meesage as seen above. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the folder `cmf` using `rm -rf /usr/share/cmf` and its working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start a new installation we need to rename the uninstallation script.
then try the structure of the CDP.
it works for me, I hope it will help you too...

[image]